# multiple if vs separate database query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
1.  $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET";
2.
3.  foreach($array as $key => $val){
4.      if($key == 'abc')
5.          $val = 'test';
6.      $sql .= $key . " = '" . $val . "' ";
7.  }
8.
9.  $sql .= "WHERE primary_key = 2";
```

Will that better to check the value in the foreach loop (line#4-5)? or to run the separate Update query?

OR

```
1.  $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET";
2.
3.  foreach($array as $key => $val){
4.      $sql .= $key . " = '" . $val . "' ";
5.  }
6.
7.  $sql .= "WHERE primary_key = 2";
8.  
9.  $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET abc = 'test'";
```

*This is a generic example, please ignore the typo and thanks in advance.

Comment: neither will work without commas `,`

Comment: @WheatBeak ...and the 2nd version DEFINITELY doesn't do what OP intended, but OP did say to please ignore the typo ;-)

Comment: This really changes nothing

Comment: And `$array['abc'] = 'test'` before `foreach`

Comment: and `i` before `e` except after "Lord knows where the OP is". @u_mulder

Comment: I suggest printing out both options and actually looking at the resulting SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.  $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET";
2.
3.  if( isset($array['abc']) ){
4.      $array['abc'] = 'test';
5.  }
6.
7.  foreach($array as $key => $val){
8.      $sql .= $key . " = '" . $val . "', ";
9.  }
10.
11.  $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
12.  $sql .= " WHERE primary_key = 2";
```

and thank you @u_mulder.